# From a sequence of numbers, how do I find an immediate smaller (and an immediate bigger) number than a particular random number, In R?

Tags: r, string, for-loop, sequence

So I have 10 increasing sequence of numbers, each of them look like (say `x(i) <- c(2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 17)` for `i` ranging from *1* to *10* ) and I have a random sampling number say `p=9`. 
Now for each sequence `x(i)`, I need to find the number immediately smaller than p and immediately bigger than p, and then for each i (from *1* to *10*) , I need to take the difference of these two numbers and store them in a string.

For the `x(i)` that I have given here, the immediate smaller number than `p=9` would be *8* and the immediate bigger number than `p=9` would be *10*, the difference of these would be *(10-8)=2*.

I am trying to get a code that would create a string of these differences, where first number of the string would mean the difference for `i=1`, second number would mean the difference for `i=2` and so on. The string would have `i` numbers. 
I am relatively new to R, so anywhere connected to loops throws me off a little bit. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I am putting the code I am working with for clarification.

```
fr = 100
dt = 1/1000 #dt in milisecond
duration = 2 #no of duration in s
nBins = 2000 #SpikeTrain
nTrials = 20 #NumberOfSimulations
MyPoissonSpikeTrain = function(p, fr= 100) {
 p = runif(nBins)
 q = ifelse(p < fr*dt, 1, 0)
  return(q)
   }

set.seed(1)
SpikeMat <- t(replicate(nTrials, MyPoissonSpikeTrain()))

Spike_times <- function(i) {
  c(dt*which( SpikeMat[i, ]==1))}


set.seed(4)
RT <- runif(1, 0 , 2)

for (i in 1:nTrials){
```

The explanation for this code, is mentioned in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754196/how-to-get-a-random-observation-point-at-a-specific-time-over-multiple-trials-in/49755472?noredirect=1#comment86729636_49755472). I have 20 (number of trials aka nTrials) strings with name `Spike_times(i)` here. Each `Spike_times(i)` is a string of time stamps between o and 2 seconds where spikes occurred and they have different number of entries. Now I have a random time sample in the form of `RT`, which is a random number between 0 and 2 seconds. Say RT is 1.17 seconds and `Spike_times(i)` are the sequence of increasing times stamps between 0 and 2 seconds.

Let me give you an example, `Spike_times(3)` looks like `0.003 0.015 0.017 ... 1.169 1.176 1.189 ... 1.985 1.990 1.997` then I need a code that picks out 1.169 and 1.176 and gives me the difference of these entries 0.007 and stores it in another string say `W` as the third entry c(_, _, 0.007, ...) and does this for all 20 strings `Spike_times(i)` and gives me `W` with 20 entries.

I hope my question is clear enough. Please let me know if I need to correct something.

Comment: It would be easier if you would provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Why do you want to store the values as characters?

Comment: ah no I didn't mean 'character' as a R language thing, sorry I forgot. I was just using it to signify the first number and the second number and so on. I am sorry If I used unclear language.

Comment: I am going to put the code I am working on in 'EDIT' , hopefully that will make things clearer @FAMG

Comment: Included my code @FAMG, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making a small change to your `Spike_times` function you can do this with `sapply` returning a vector of all calculated values

```
Spike_times <- function(i) {
    x <- c(dt*which( SpikeMat[i, ]==1))
    min(x[x > RT]) - max(x[x < RT])
}

set.seed(4)
RT <- runif(1, 0 , 2)

results <- sapply(1:20, Spike_times)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. I couldn't use your code as it is, because I needed Spike_times function as it is, for other reasons, but I tweaked your code into:

    `distances <- function(i) {`
     `Spike_times(i)`
     `min(Spike_times(i)[Spike_times(i) > RT])- max(Spike_times(i)` 
     `[Spike_times(i) < RT] )`
      `}`

    `result <- sapply(1:nTrials, distances)`

and I think I got the results I wanted.

Comment: Just to clarify, I haven't used the function `min` or `max` like we have used here and this sort of usage isn't obvious from help in R, the way I understand it is, `min(x[x<y])` means here, _minimum of x such that x is less than y_. Is my understanding correct and can I generally use `min`, `max` function in this way?

Comment: `min(x[x < y])` means the minimum value in x for all values in x less than y, however this is pretty useless as min(x) would just return the same thing, unless `y` is less than all values in `x` which would return an error. The way that I have used it `min(x[x > RT])` means the minimum value of x of those that are greater than RT

Comment: To have a better understanding of what is happening try running the commands in the console from inside out i.e. `x < y` then `x[x < y]` and then `min(x[x < y])`

Answer (score 2):

This approach should do what you want. I am making a function that extracts the desired result from a single sequence and then applying it to each sequence. I am assuming here that your sequences are row-vectors and are stacked in a matrix. If your actual data structure is different the code can be adapted, but you need to indicate how your sequences are actually stored.

```r
x <- matrix(rep(c(2,3,5,6,8,10,11,17), 10), nrow=10, byrow = T)
x
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#>  [1,]    2    3    5    6    8   10   11   17
#>  [2,]    2    3    5    6    8   10   11   17
#>  [3,]    2    3    5    6    8   10   11   17
#>  [4,]    2    3    5    6    8   10   11   17
#>  [5,]    2    3    5    6    8   10   11   17
#>  [6,]    2    3    5    6    8   10   11   17
#>  [7,]    2    3    5    6    8   10   11   17
#>  [8,]    2    3    5    6    8   10   11   17
#>  [9,]    2    3    5    6    8   10   11   17
#> [10,]    2    3    5    6    8   10   11   17

set.seed(123)
p = sample(10, 1)

# write a function to do what you want on one sequence:
# NOTE: If p appears in the sequence I assume you want the 
# closest numbers not equal to p! If you want the closest
# numbers to p including p itself change the less than/
# greater than to <= / >=
get_l_r_diff <- function(row, p) {
  temp <- row - p
  lower <- max(row[temp < 0])
  upper <- min(row[temp > 0])
  upper - lower
}

apply(x, 1, function(row)get_l_r_diff(row, p))
#>  [1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3

apply(x, 1, function(row) get_l_r_diff(row, 9))
#>  [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

# if the result really needs to be a string
paste(apply(x, 1, function(row) get_l_r_diff(row, 9)), collapse = "")
#> [1] "2222222222"
```

For your case you can just apply the two functions to your indices:

```r
spikes <- sapply(1:20, function(i){get_l_r_diff(Spike_times(i), RT)})
```

Comment: Hi @gfgm , thank you for your answer. My input is not a matrix but a function of `i` where `i` ranges from 1 to 20. I have made an edit in my question for more clarification. I am trying to adapt your code to fit mine but I am not sure how to get started since I am very new to R. What do I replace your variable `row` with. Please help.